# How do you supply a default value to a string option in Options.Applicative

Tags: haskell

How do you indicate a default value via `strOption`? The [documentation for the optparse-applicative library](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative) doesn't show how to create a default value for a strOption, e.g.,

```
data Sample = Sample
  { hello :: String
  , quiet :: Bool }

sample :: Parser Sample
sample = Sample
     <$> strOption
         ( long "hello"
        <> metavar "TARGET"
        <> help "Target for the greeting" )
     <*> switch
         ( long "quiet"
        <> help "Whether to be quiet" )
```

though it does show how to supply default values for flag options. E.g., `Normal` is the default in

```
data Verbosity = Normal | Verbose

flag Normal Verbose
  ( long "verbose"
 <> short 'v'
 <> help "Enable verbose mode"
```

**EDIT**

I think I found the answer in the `value` modifier in `Options.Applicative.Builder`.

Comment: If you've found the answer, please add it as your own answer so that people can vote on it and that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the readme:

> > Parsers are instances of both Applicative and Alternative

Which means you should just be able to specify default values like this:

```
someOption <|> pure "thisIsUsedIfSomeOptionWasn'tPassed"
```

You could create a default combinator like this

```
 defaultValue :: Alternative f => a -> f a -> f a
 defaultValue = flip (<|>) . pure
```

And use it like this

```
 optionWithDefault :: Parser String
 optionWithDefault = defaultValue "defaultValue" option
```

I'd be surprised if that didn't exist already in some form though.

Answer (score 19):

This does indeed exist, as [`value`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.8.0.1/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#v:value), although it's rather hard to find in the documentation.

Example:

```
strOption  ( long "some-opt"
          <> value "default value"
          <> metavar "SOMEOPT"
          <> help "an option demonstrating the use of `value'" )
```